# Css for specific page is not working

Tags: css

i got a little css problem, when i try to change something for just specific page or post. Like in this case i would like to change the background color of the entry content of page number 2458. And its working

```
#post-2458 .entry-content {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

But right here i use same logic and i try to change the col 8 background color for page 2458, but it does not workss. Sure if i do it without #post-2458 it changes, but it changes for all pages and i would like to do that only for page of that id.

```
#post-2458 .col-md-8 {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Am i missing something out? could you advice how to adjust that code pls? BTW im using custom css plugin to put in that codes.
Thank you

Comment: i think to `.col-md-8` you didn't mention any width.Add `.col-md-8` css.

Comment: Put your HTML code here to find the issue.

Comment: Im not sure what kind of html you would like to see, my knowledge of  html and css is just using the custom css plugin + som basic html to change color and so on.

actually the real post number should be 2113 and here is what i inspected from page. I would like to change tha col md-8 just for that specic post 2113. If i use it with primary, it will change it for every page.

Comment: <div id="primary" class="col-md-8 mb-xs-24 sidebar-right">
   <article id="post-2113" class="post-content post-grid-wide post-2113 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized tag-ako-schudnut tag-ako-schudnut-rychlo tag-bmr tag-chudnutie tag-dieta tag-kalorie tag-mukistylefitness tag-tdee">

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding it with this:

```
#post-2458 .col-md-8 {
  background-color: #fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do few things:

Add *!important* to see if it's all about the style weights.

```
#post-2458 .col-md-8 {
   background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Go to inspect tab of your browser and check which styles overrides yours or which styles you just overridden. In most cases you can override other styles just by correct reference.

For example this might NOT work:

```
#post-2458 .col-md-8 {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

But this could work, since maybe you are trying to override background-color given by the reference *.col-md-8.sidebar-right*

```
#post-2458 .col-md-8.sidebar-right {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

There are lots of maybe's, since it is hard to give you proper solution without a link to the website in which your problem occurs. Check the weights and make sure to override correct styles. I hope it helps!

Comment: can you pls tell me how to chek in inspector what style overrides what?
Important does not work

Comment: @MariánChrást Inspect the element you want to style, in the Styles tab you want to find styles for specific attribute, in your case background-color. After you find the lines responsible for applying the style (eg. '.example.example-container{ background-color: blue; }'), you want to copy the selector, in this case it's .example.example-container and within the same manner define styles in your plugin. If it still does not work, add important, if still nothing, then maybe you should add styles dynamically :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add some id to div which you want to change and operate directly on id. Don't use col-md-8 to avoid troubles. When you want to make changes only for one element id is the best option and I has a bigger importance than class and don't use !important if you can fix something smarter.

Comment: Here is the page,  http://www.mukistylefitness.sk/chudnutie/ , and the purpose is to have white bacground underneath the content section. It means also the comment section is with white background  like it is on this page  http://www.mukistylefitness.sk/zdravy-recept-bez-vycitiek/.
Can you advice how to make that division and where to put it?